# PCL error in ROS fuerte

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mkdir -p bin

cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find  osbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package New
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags

Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only New
CMake Error at /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKTargets.cmake:16 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
Command add_executable() is not scriptable

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake:231 (INCLUDE)
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (FIND_PACKAGE)
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/vtk_include.cmake:1 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'New'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

---

I am facing this error to compile my packages.
Can anybody help me.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
ROS fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64501/pcl-error-in-ros-fuerte/) by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-06-07**:
same issue here too

**Comment by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) on 2013-06-07**:
Seeing the same as well when compiling husky_simulator in fuerte on 12.04. The same package on the same machine works fine in groovy.

**Comment by [yanma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5081/yanma/) on 2013-06-07**:
This is effecting gazebo plugins compilation as well, since gazebo seems depends on perception_pcl. Seem to be broken by a Ubuntu update this week.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-06-07**:
thats true, after update, the package is not compiling, pls post the answer once you solve the issue

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-06-10**:
Same problem with laser_scan_matcher ...

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-06-11**:
would be great if one of you could post a bug report on github and post the link to it here

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-06-12**:
somebody did @brice rebsamen https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using fuerte on 12.04, and had the same problem. Here's my workaround and now I can rosmake my packages again! Since the error occurred at the perception_pcl stack, I overlaid it and recompiled the stack with the patch in my own workspace, thanks to this post

> answers.ros.org/question/49447/error-with-pcl_ros-in-ros-fuerte/.

During the recompilation of the stack, it also bit me with another couple of errors, e.g., I had to softlink the GL header folder, and rebuild VTK with the -fPIC option (because I manually installed VTK previously with all default options).

Here are the steps, which are just a workaround and I hope a real solution is coming with a good ROS update.

1. Copy the perception_pcl stack from /opt/ros/ to your workspace, and cd into it.
2. rosws set pcl.
3. rosws update pcl.
   (After this, resource your setup.bash file, and check if the new stack is in your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)
4. Install the patch:

> code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5243/perception_pcl-1.0.1-vtk5.8.patch.

5. Delete all build folders (found two in pcl/ and pcl/msg/, respectively).
6. rosmake pcl (Don't forget to delete the ROS_NOBUILD dummy beforehand)
   (Here I was given a compiling error related to VTK. If you luckily don't have it, go straight to Step 9.)
7. Re-do your VTK.

   1. cd into your VTK source folder.
   2. mkdir build and cd into it.
   3. cmake .. gave me a missing file error as "file STRINGS file "/usr/local/include/GL/glx.h" cannot be read".
   4. sudo ln -s /usr/include/GL /usr/local/include
   5. ccmake . to configure your VTK
   6. make CFLAGS=-fPIC
   7. sudo make install
8. rosmake pcl.
9. rosmake your_package.
10. YEH!

---

Originally posted by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) with karma: 166 on 2013-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on 2013-06-09**:
@Jiayi Liu.it did not work for me. i have installed ROS-fuerte by using apt-get. Steps I have followed are.I have confusion at 4th step and 5th step.I am new to Ubuntu and ROS might b i am doing mistakes. The output of 4th step is "patching file manifest.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31.
1 out of 1 hunk FA"

**Comment by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) on 2013-06-10**:
Hey @Muhammad Atif. By saying "install", I mean making changes to corresponding files, according to [the diffs](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5243/perception_pcl-1.0.1-vtk5.8.patch). Btw, how did you get that output?

**Comment by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on 2013-06-10**:
@Jiayi Liu.Now I have done the same just change the files.One thing i want to tell you i installed ROS by "apt-get".I have copied the perception_pcl package from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks to /home/atif/fuerte_workspace. i have my package is /home/atif/fuerte_workspace/sandbox I am doing rite ?

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-06-11**:
Hi Jiayi, when i modified "cmake -P ${prefix}/vtk_include.cmake`" lflags="-L`cmake -P ${prefix}/vtk_library.cmake" to "cat ${prefix}/vtk_include_dirs.txt`" lflags="-L`cat ${prefix}/vtk_library_dirs.txt", this is what I got (next comment!)

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-06-11**:
"cat: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/vtk_include_dirs.txt: No such file or directory".

rosmake pcl didnt show any errors.

Should I have deleted the perception_pcl stack at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks?

Bythe way, what do you mean by redo VTK? Where shld the source file be at?

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-06-11**:
my package is in ~/fuerte_workspace/ btw!

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-06-11**:
The above answer worked when I installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte and solved the issue

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-06-11**:
Thank you. It work.

**Comment by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) on 2013-06-12**:
@Muhammad Atif. 1) As shown in ROS documentation, apt-get is the correct way to install ROS stack binaries, which downloads the stacks to your /opt path.

**Comment by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) on 2013-06-12**:
2) You are right. Make sure to run Step 2-3 to put the new pcl in the ROS PACK PATH. You can try "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" to check the new stack is shown.

**Comment by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) on 2013-06-12**:
Hi @VicL, 1) it seems that your overlay is not working as expected. Your rosbuild still finds perception_pcl in the /opt path instead of your workspace. Use rosws to setup the overlay, and use "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" to check the stack shows up in your workspace.

**Comment by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) on 2013-06-12**:
2) I won't suggest you do that. 3) Because long time ago I had a manual installation of VTK without creating a shared library (the -fPIC option), which caused a building error in Step 6. So if you were not messing with VTK from source code, you shouldn't worry about the entire Step 7.

**Comment by [jemalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5131/jemalo/) on 2013-06-12**:
Thanks a lot, it works for me (ROS fuerte + Ubuntu 12.04). But when I launch move_base, it cannot find the file libpcl-ros-tf.so. Then I've re-installed "ros-fuerte-perception-pcl" and move_base runs all right. I hope that someone can propose a better solution.